# Tensorflow training got stuck after some steps, how to investigate?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a python script to train a Tensorflow model similar to the one in CIFAR-10 tutorial. I have 20500 training examples and am using 128 examples per batch. I set 1,000,000 as the max number of steps. However after about 164,000 steps, the python script seems stuck somewhere. Is there any way to find out where the script is stuck? My last resort would be using Ctrl-C to terminate the process and force it to print out a backtrace. But I wonder if there are other things I should check before I kill the process.

Here's the train loop:

```
def train(trainingData, batchSize, workingDir, maxSteps):
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    image, label = readData(trainingData)
    minAfterDequeue = 5000
    capacity = minAfterDequeue + 3 * batchSize
    imageBatch, labelBatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=batchSize, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=minAfterDequeue)
    #labelBatch = tf.reshape(labelBatch, [batchSize, 1])
    #tf.image_summary('images', imageBatch)
    #tf.histogram_summary('labels', tf.cast(labelBatch, tf.float32))

    logits = network.inference(imageBatch, 0.5)
    #floatLabel = tf.cast(labelBatch, tf.float32)
    #cross_entropy_per_example = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, floatLabel)
    loss, cross_entropy = network.loss(logits, labelBatch)
    train_op = network.train(loss, global_step, batchSize)

    # Create a saver
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

    session = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    session.run(init)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=session)

    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(workingDir, session.graph_def)

    for step in xrange(maxSteps):
        start_time = time.time()
        #l, sm, ce = session.run([floatLabel, logits, cross_entropy_per_example])
        #print l
        #print sm
        #print ce
        _, loss_value = session.run([train_op, loss])
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        assert not np.isnan(loss_value), 'Model diverged with loss = NaN'

        if step % 10 == 0:
            examples_per_sec = batchSize / duration
            format_str = "%s: step %d, loss = %e (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f sec/batch"
            print (format_str % (datetime.now(), step, loss_value, examples_per_sec, float(duration)))

        if step % 100 == 0:
            summary_str = session.run(summary_op)
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)

        if step % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == maxSteps:
            checkpoint_path = os.path.join(workingDir, 'model.ckpt')
            saver.save(session, checkpoint_path, global_step = step)
```

And here's the various functions used to construct the graph:

```
import re
import tensorflow as tf

TOWER_NAME="tower"

NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH = 50000
# Constants describing the training process.
MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY = 0.9999     # The decay to use for the moving average.
NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY = 350.0      # Epochs after which learning rate decays.
LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR = 0.95 # Learning rate decay factor.
INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE = 0.01       # Initial learning rate.

def _activation_summary(x):
    """Helper to create summaries for activations.
    Creates a summary that provides a histogram of activations.
    Creates a summary that measure the sparsity of activations.
    Args:
        x: Tensor
    Returns:
        nothing
    """
    # Remove 'tower_[0-9]/' from the name in case this is a multi-GPU training
    # session. This helps the clarity of presentation on tensorboard.
    tensor_name = re.sub('%s_[0-9]*/' % TOWER_NAME, '', x.op.name)
    tf.histogram_summary(tensor_name + '/activations', x)
    tf.scalar_summary(tensor_name + '/sparsity', tf.nn.zero_fraction(x))
    #numChannel = tf.shape(x)[3]
    #tf.image_summary(tensor_name + '/image', tf.reshape(x)

def _variable_on_cpu(name, shape, initializer):
    """Helper to create a Variable stored on CPU memory.
    Args:
        name: name of the variable
        shape: list of ints
        initializer: initializer for Variable
    Returns:
        Variable Tensor
    """
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=initializer, dtype=tf.float32)
    return var

def _variable_with_weight_decay(name, shape, stddev, wd=None):
    """Helper to create an initialized Variable with weight decay.
    Note that the Variable is initialized with a truncated normal distribution.
    A weight decay is added only if one is specified.
    Args:
        name: name of the variable
        shape: list of ints
        stddev: standard deviation of a truncated Gaussian
        wd: add L2Loss weight decay multiplied by this float. If None, weight
            decay is not added for this Variable.
    Returns:
        Variable Tensor
    """
    var = _variable_on_cpu(name, shape, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))
    if wd is not None:
        weight_decay = tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, name='weight_loss')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
    return var

def inference(images, dropout):
    # conv1
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 1, 32], stddev=5e-2)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [32], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(conv1)

    # pool1
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')

    # conv2
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 32, 64], stddev=5e-2)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(conv2)

    # pool2
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

    # conv3
    with tf.variable_scope('conv3') as scope:
        kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 64, 64], stddev=5e-2)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        conv3 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(conv3)

    # pool 3
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool3')

    # fully connected 4
    with tf.variable_scope('full4') as scope:
        batchSize = pool3.get_shape()[0].value
        flattened = tf.reshape(pool3, [batchSize, -1])
        dim = flattened.get_shape()[1].value
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 256], stddev=5e-2)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [256], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        full4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flattened, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
        full4_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(full4, dropout)
        _activation_summary(full4)
        #_activation_summary(full4_dropout)

    # fully connected 5
    with tf.variable_scope('full5') as scope:
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [256, 128], stddev=5e-2)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [128], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        full5 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(full4_dropout, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
        full5_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(full5, dropout)
        _activation_summary(full5)
        #_activation_summary(full5_dropout)

    # softmax
    with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
        weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [128, 2], stddev=1/128.0)
        biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [2], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(full5_dropout, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
        _activation_summary(softmax_linear)

    return softmax_linear

def loss(logits, labels):
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)

    return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss'), cross_entropy_mean

def _add_loss_summaries(total_loss):
    """Add summaries for losses in CIFAR-10 model.
    Generates moving average for all losses and associated summaries for
    visualizing the performance of the network.
    Args:
        total_loss: Total loss from loss().
    Returns:
        loss_averages_op: op for generating moving averages of losses.
    """
    # Compute the moving average of all individual losses and the total loss.
    loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
    losses = tf.get_collection('losses')
    loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])

    # Attach a scalar summary to all individual losses and the total loss; do the
    # same for the averaged version of the losses.
    for l in losses + [total_loss]:
        # Name each loss as '(raw)' and name the moving average version of the loss
        # as the original loss name.
        tf.scalar_summary(l.op.name +' (raw)', l)
        tf.scalar_summary(l.op.name, loss_averages.average(l))

    return loss_averages_op

def train(loss, step, batchSize):
    numBatchesPerEpoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH / batchSize
    decay_steps = int(numBatchesPerEpoch * NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY)

    # Decay the learning rate exponentially based on the number of steps.
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE,
                                    step,
                                    decay_steps,
                                    LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR,
                                    staircase=True)
    tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate', lr)

    loss_averages_op = _add_loss_summaries(loss)

    # compute gradients
    with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
        opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
        grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)

    # apply gradients
    apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step = step)

    # add histograms for trainable variables
    for var in tf.trainable_variables():
        tf.histogram_summary(var.op.name, var)

    # add histograms for gradients:
    for grad, var in grads:
        if grad is not None:
            tf.histogram_summary(var.op.name + '/gradients', grad)

    # Track the moving average of all trainable variables
    variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, step)
    variable_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

    with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradient_op, variable_averages_op]):
        train_op = tf.no_op(name='train')

    return train_op
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your training loop? There might be a space leak in your problem that's causing it to do more work each time around the loop. Calling `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` before the training loop starts is one way to catch some of these.

Comment: Another trick to rule out Queue starvation, is to create session with `tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(operation_timeout_in_ms=20000))` That way you'll get `DeadlineExceeded` exception instead of hanging

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I added the timeout config as you suggested, but immediately ran into DeadlineExceeded exception on dequeue_many() after only a couple of dozen steps. All my training data is from a single TFRecord file, and I'm using batch of 128. So I'm not sure why I'd ran into timeout so quickly. Previously, without the timeout, the script start showing slowdown only after thousands of steps.

Comment: You could use `try/except` to make your code robust to DeadlineExceeded exceptions.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I assume you are suggesting to catch the exception and go onto the next iteration of the train loop. But if I don't resolve the cause of timeout, don't I just get another exception, since I'm reading from the same queue on the same file?

Comment: It may resolve the cause of timeout if the cause is a race condition. The more robust approach is to carefully analyze possible configurations of your queues and make sure you don't have such situation.

Comment: That makes sense. But in this case, it's puzzling that there's a race condition, since I'm using shuffle_batch with just one thread. `imageBatch, labelBatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=batchSize, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=minAfterDequeue)`, where `image` and `label` come from a `TFRecordReader` on a `string_input_producer`.